# ReactJS TestUtils Garbage Collection

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-testutils

For ReactJS's test utility class : TestUtils, how do they handle garbage collection?
There are no methods that de-allocate or destroy a React Module that was created beforehand in renderIntoDocument method

Here's a link to the source
https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/87bcbff21896e6b362012a0bc82c35d42a6f955d/src/test/ReactTestUtils.js

For clarity TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(); would initialize the data, but how do I unmount this component or remove this component completely?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For clarity TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<SomeComponent metaData={data}/>); would initialize the data, but how do I unmount this component or remove this component completely?

Comment: Please clarify by editing your question, not commenting.